# Create a tally system with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a simple tally system to record the data-id from the elements that are selected and combine the data-id values at the end to generate a result.

```
function myAnswer() {
  document.getElementById('btnNxt').removeAttribute('disabled');
  var myResult = '';
  var iId = this.getAttribute('data-id');
  myObj[page].mySel = iId;
  myQueRep[page] = iId;
  console.log(iId);
  for (var x = 0; x < btn.length; x++) {
    if (iId == x) {
      btn[x].classList.add('selAnswer');
    } else {
      btn[x].classList.remove('selAnswer');
    }
 }
```

}

In this section, the iId variable gets the data-id value but I'm not sure how to tally the selections up and display a result based on that score.

**JSFiddle of current code:**

https://jsfiddle.net/mkykmg15/2/

Comment: If you truly want a "system" then make some fundamental quiz objects. Existing code will get simpler because it will be using objects and their methods, not futzing with every individual variable in nested scopes. Tallying will be a consequence: `Player.score` might be as simple as `return Quiz.score(Player.answers)`.  I see these objects: `Question`, `Quiz` (a collection of questions), `Player`, `Page` (maybe).  Questions may need unique IDs for easy referencing, answer checking, etc. That might get rid of the page counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing something with your `myQueRep`.

So something like:

```js
var myQueRep = ["1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2"]

var tally = myQueRep.reduce( function (acc, curr) {
  return acc + +curr
}, 0);

console.log(tally)
```